# Get objects from current site without settings.SITE_ID

Tags: django, django-sites

I'm looking for the same functionality as the CurrentSiteManager provides but without having to specify SITE_ID in settings.py as [the CurrentSiteManager requires](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2e1f674897e89bbc69a389696773aebfec601916/django/contrib/sites/managers.py#L60). Information about the current site should come from the request. My take on the problem would be to make a custom manager, but is there something I'm missing? What would be a good way of doing this? It seems quite trivial that the CurrentSiteManager should provide this functionality. Would it make sense to submit a feature request?

Comment: The code you linked to is over a year old - the [latest version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2e1f674897e89bbc69a389696773aebfec601916/django/contrib/sites/models.py) of the `SiteManager` implements a host-based approach which gets the current site from the hostname if no SITE_ID is defined.

Comment: See also https://github.com/django/django/pull/3293

Comment: @solarissmoke: I'm already using the SiteManager, but the CurrentSiteManager doesn't provide that functionality. I want an equivalent to User.objects.all() that only returns users associated to the current site (usually User.on_site.all(), but that requires SITE_ID to be set).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying. I have posted an answer that I think explains why this isn't something that Django can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> Information about the current site should come from the request.

There is a big assumption here, which is that the manager will always have a request context available.

This isn't an assumption that Django can make: any generic model manager must work outside of a request context because there are all sorts of cases where a request context isn't available - e.g., management commands, migrations, tasks, etc. Even if you are in the context of a request, your manager has no knowledge of this unless you explicitly pass it to any method on the manager (i.e., you need those methods to accept a `request` argument). This is why `CurrentSiteManager` [requires a `SITE_ID`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#the-currentsitemanager):

> The CurrentSiteManager is only usable when the `SITE_ID` setting is defined in your settings.

If you do want to filter objects within a request context, then Django provides the [`CurrentSiteMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware) to add the current site to all requests. Within your views you can then filter objects on this `site`.

There are examples of projects that have implemented a custom `CurrentSiteManager` that does what you're asking for  - the one that comes to mind is [Mezzanine](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/core/managers.py#L365-L386) which you may be able to borrow from (note that it involves messing around with thread locals, and still requires a fallback to a `SITE_ID` setting).